# Can't get result from where condition with variables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is how i'm trying to get the type of certificate with where condition , but still recieve
nothing from this query:

```
$res= student::find($student, ['typecertificate']); 
$k = certificate::select('id-cer')->where('name-cer','=',$res)->get(); 
return $k;
```

Comment: Critical data is missing in your question. What is $student? What is the result of $res query?

Comment: $student is a table with all student information ( id , name , grade , certificateType), $res contains the type of the certificate and $k supposed to give me the id of certificate according to the type , but the problem is when i'm using a variable in the where statement i can get nothing

Comment: $student = new student;
$student=student::latest('id')->first();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'm assuming you want to retrieve the field `certificateType` from the latest record that was inserted in the `students` table.

You can achieve that without a where clause, by directly using the Eloquent Builder to retrieve only that specific field like this:

```
Student::latest()->first('certificateType');
```

But this would give you an Eloquent Collection with one element. If you just want the value (not wrapped in a collection), you can simply retrieve the latest student and get the corresponding field directly:

```
$certificateType = Student::latest()->first()->certificateType;
```

I could explain more, but your question is vague and your database schema isn't clear either, so I'd need more information on that as well as what you intend to achieve.

In any case, Laravel's documentation is often a big help: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models